# Geany: Syntax highlighting for #define

Tags: syntax-highlighting, text-editor, geany

```
#define ll long long
```

Sometimes Geany syntax highlight `ll` automatically for me and sometimes it just didn't work at all. I tried close and reopen several times and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Can anybody tell me the reason for this weird behavior?

Note: I'm using Mac 10.11.6 and Geany 1.36 (if it helps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `typedef` for defining types.

The syntax using `ll = long long;` is more modern.

For a simple type definition it does exactly the same as `typedef long long ll;`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Geany determines the filetype based on two things: the extension name and the shebang. E.g. if you call your file foo.c it's recognized as a C-file. baa.cpp will be handled as C++.